# Is there a good way to store an array in a MOSS custom content type?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I need to store an array in a custom content type in MOSS.  This will always be hidden, only used programmatically.  Throughout the lifecycle of the list item, I will be adding values to the array.  My array may look like this after a while:

```
value1,1 | value1,2 | value1,3 | value1,4
value2,1 | value2,2 | value2,3 |
value3,1 | value3,2 | value3,3 |
value4,1 | value4,2 | value4,3 | value4,4
```

I know I can use SPFieldMultiColumn to store the first row, but it doesn't look like I can store multiple rows.  I also know I can just create a text field and serialize my array myself.  Just curious if there's already a field to use when you need to store an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out of the box field in which you can store a 2-dimensional array.
Usually, you either store each row in a different item, or you serialize your value in a simpler field (like multiline text).

Comment: As a followup, how do I serialize without first writing a file?  See my question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302821/serialization-in-c-without-using-file-system

Comment: I'm using data classes and JavaScriptSerializer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Serializing it is probably your best solution for small arrays.  Or you can store it in a separate list.  And remember there's no law against creating your own custom table.